# Dropdowns selected Items inside the page when am I trying to export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a GridView inside of a Repeater and I'm exporting to Excel without problem. When I try to use the DropDown.SelectedValue to put inside the GridView's headers using the RowCreated event, I always get the first item instead of the SelectedValue. Can someone help me with that?

I have 2 dropdowns ddlType and ddlYear and always it give me back the first item's value:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    if (ddlType.SelectedValue != "0")
        contador = int.Parse(ddlType.SelectedValue)-1;

    GridViewRow rowHeader = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    string HeaderBackColor = "#EDEDED";
    rowHeader.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HeaderBackColor);

    Literal newCells = new Literal();
    newCells.Text = ddlYear.SelectedValue+@"</th>" +
     "</tr>" +
     "<tr bgcolor='" + HeaderBackColor + "'>";

    newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='8' style='width:100px' >" + typeA + "</th>" +

     "</tr>" +
     "<tr bgcolor='" + HeaderBackColor + "'>";



    switch (Nav)
    {
        case "0":
            newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='2' style='width:80px' >item1</th>
                               <th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>item2</th> 
                               <th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>item3</th>
                               <th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>tem4</th>";
            break;
        case "1":
            newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='2' style='width:80px' >item1</th>";
            break;
        case "2":
            newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>item2</th>";
            break;
        case "3":
            newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>item3</th>";
            break;
        case "4":
            newCells.Text += @"<th colspan='2' style='width:80px'>item4</th>";
            break;

    }

    newCells.Text += @"</tr><tr bgcolor='" + HeaderBackColor + "'>";

    if(Nav=="0")
        newCells.Text += @"<th>N</th>
                          <th>E</th>

                          <th>N</th>
                          <th>E</th>

                          <th>N</th>
                          <th>E</th>

                          <th>N</th>
                          <th>E";
    else
        newCells.Text += @"<th>N</th>
                           <th>E";

    TableCellCollection cells = e.Row.Cells;
    TableHeaderCell headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();

    headerCell.RowSpan = 4;
    headerCell.Controls.Add(newCells);

    headerCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#6495ED");
    headerCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFF");


    rowHeader.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    rowHeader.Visible = true;


    ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, rowHeader);
}
```

I'm exporting to Excel using this:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Contacts.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
MyRepeater.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Where are you putting these 2 routines?

Comment: the first inside the GridView RowCreated event and the second button onclick event

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled on your DropDowns?

Comment: Yeah its enable and I realize that my textBoxs are all empty too

Comment: The first code works well when I use it just to show the items, the problem is when I try to export to excel, the xls file is genereted, but the selected item used to put inside the grid header back always the first, not the real selected item

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you need to set your DataSource and call DataBind() again to re-initialize the GridView. It seems to be disappearing on PostBack.

Comment: I solved my problem using ViewState, but I really don't know why this happened.

Comment: I asked about the ViewState awhile ago.  What needed the ViewState?

Comment: I know, you asked about ViewState DropDrown property and I solved using like that: ViewState["test"]. The asp.net components still with the same problem.

Comment: It was not the best way, because I need to populate those ViewStates with this two dropdown values

Comment: There's got to be something else like the DataBind().  Where do you bind the data?  You should post the code that handles the binding of the data.